# EXPRESS - Some API endpoints are not found despite valid request

Tags: node.js, rest, express, endpoint, insomnia

I have a simple Reddit clone project written in express. I noticed that some endpoints are throwing errors despite having a correct URL. Here is my code.

**App.js**

```
app.use("/api", router);
```

**Router**

```
router.route("/register")
  .post(UsersController.APIregisterUser);

router.route("/login") 
  .post(UsersController.APIlogin);

router.route("/posts/") // Fetch all posts
  .get(PostsController.APIgetPosts)
  .post(Utility.verifyToken, PostsController.APIaddPost);

router.route("/comment/submit/:id/") // /posts/comment/123456789
  .put(Utility.verifyAndPassData, PostsController.APIaddComment);

router.route("/posts/vote")
  .put(Utility.verifyAndPassData, PostsController.APIcastVote);

router.route("/posts/:id/") // req.params.id
  .get(PostsController.APIgetPostByID)
  .delete(Utility.verifyToken, PostsController.APIdeletePost);

router.route("/posts/categories")
  .get(PostsController.APIgetCategories);
```

When I try to fetch all posts by going to `http://localhost:8080/api/posts` (GET) via Insomnia, it works as intended. However, when I try to post a comment by going to `http://localhost:8080/api/comment/submit/*post's id*` (PUT) , it says 404 not found. I checked the `PostsController.APIaddComment` if the error is in there but there seems to be no error on that part. I even tried replacing the whole function with a `console.log("test")` to see if the endpoint is being reached but none happens.

Here is the `PostsController.APIaddComment`:

```
  static async APIaddComment(userData, req, res, next) {
    try {
      const commentBody = {
        user: req.body.username,
        body: req.body.body,
        date: new Date() 
      }

      const addComment = await PostsDAO.addComment(commentBody, req.params.id);
      res.status(200).json({ 
        status: "Comment submitted!",
        addComment
      });

    } catch(e) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: `Error in PostsController APIaddComment: ${e}`
      })
    }
  }
```

Other than that particular function, everything works as intended. What could be the possible cause?

Comment: I am not sure,  but you can test replacing router.route("/comment/submit/:id/") with router.route("/comment/submit/:id").  Sometimes trailing slash raise unexpected behaviour.  You can try without last trailing slash. If it works then let me know

Comment: It's now working. Thank you for the suggestion. But why and how does a trailing slash cause errors?

Comment: A slash is a character like any else `/foo` and `/foo/` are simply not the same thing. Urls are not the same thing as paths on a filesystem